# Find and print the total number of menu items and the average price of the menu items for each restaurant

Tags: mysql

For this, I have the query:

```
SELECT r.restaurantName, COUNT(m.itemNo), AVG(m.price)
FROM Restaurant r
INNER JOIN MenuItem m
ON m.restaurantNo = r.restaurantID
INNER JOIN Dish d
ON d.dishNo = m.dishNo;
```

It generates this result:

```
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| restaurantName | COUNT(m.itemNo) | AVG(m.price) |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
| Tasty Thai     |              12 |    11.479167 |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

So, it is displaying the correct average, however, it has picked ALL menu items I added to the table instead of just for each individual restaurant, as well as counting all of the items. It also is only displaying one of the three restaurants I inserted.

How do I fix this?

Database code:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant(restaurantID Integer Primary Key, restaurantName Char(15) NOT NULL, type Char(15) NOT NULL, city char(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Dish(dishNo Integer Primary Key, dishName Char(15) NOT NULL, type ENUM ('ap', 'en', 'ds'));

CREATE TABLE MenuItem(itemNo Integer Primary Key, restaurantNo int, dishNo int, price DECIMAL(4,2) CHECK(price IN(price>=5 and price<=50)), FOREIGN KEY(restaurantNo) REFERENCES Restaurant(restaurantID) ON DELETE NO ACTION, FOREIGN KEY(dishNo) REFERENCES Dish(dishNo) ON DELETE SET NULL);

CREATE TABLE FoodOrder(orderNo Integer Primary Key, itemNo int, dateof date CHECK(dateof IN(dateof>='2017-01-01')), timeof time, FOREIGN KEY(itemNo) REFERENCES MenuItem(itemNo) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing GROUP BY:

```
SELECT r.restaurantName, COUNT(m.itemNo), AVG(m.price)
FROM Restaurant r
INNER JOIN MenuItem m
ON m.restaurantNo = r.restaurantID
INNER JOIN Dish d
ON d.dishNo = m.dishNo
GROUP BY r.restaurantName;
```